# Prove that a logisitic population grows fastest when it reaches half its carrying capacity.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given equations: $\frac{dP}{Dt}$ = kP(1-$\frac{P}{L}$); P(t) = $\frac{L}{1-Ae^{-kt}}$; A = $\frac{L-Po}{Po}$

My work so far:

$\frac{dP}{Dt}$ = kP(1-$\frac{P}{L}$)

I'm not really sure what to do but here's what I was able to copy down of what my class did.  I've got no idea what or if any of it is right or wrong.

$\frac{dP^{2}}{d^{2}t}$ = $\frac{-k}{L}$P + k (1-$\frac{P}{L}$)

$\frac{dP^{2}}{d^{2}t}$ = $\frac{-k}{L}$P + k$\frac{-k}{L}$P = k - $\frac{2kP}{L}$

P = $\frac{L}{2}$

That's as far as my class got.
I understand that I need to derive it and find an inflection point but I guess it gets confusing when k and L are constants!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This almost done. The time the population grows fastest is when the first derivative of $P$ is maximum. First derivative of $P$ achieves maximum at possible critical points, i.e., the points where the second derivative is $0$.

Your second last step is to find the second derivative of $P$ and set it to $0$. So
$$k-\frac{2kP}{L}=0\\
k=\frac{2kP}{L}$$

The answer was found to be $P=\frac{L}{2}$.

Next you need either to use first derivative test or second derivative test to show that it is a maximum instead of a minimum. I would think the second derivative test is easier, in which you should find the third derivative of $P$ (the second derivative of the growth rate of $P$) and show that it is negative.